# Use mutate with column names in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to sum the NA values in between variables in my dataset. I can do it using mutate in dplyr but somehow I've only managed to do it using the column numbers and not the column names which is quite annoying because I have a rather large number of variables and I might drop some of them.

Here is the code that I have:

```
    master_clean <- master_clean %>%
       mutate(nbNA_pt1 =rowSums(is.na(master_clean[,c(1:3)])),
         nbNA_pt2 = rowSums(is.na(master_clean[,c(4:6)])),
         nbNA_pt3 = rowSums(is.na(master_clean[,c(7:9)]))
         )
```

And here is what I would like to have:

```
    master_clean <- master_clean %>%
         mutate(nbNA_pt1 = rowSums(is.na(master_clean[,c("Q1":"Q12")])),
         nbNA_pt2 = rowSums(is.na(master_clean[,c("Q13":"Q20")])),
         nbNA_pt3 = rowSums(is.na(master_clean[,c("Q21":"Q90")]))
         )
```

Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `master_clean[,c("Q13":"Q20")]` with `across(Q13:Q20)`.

Comment: @MartinGal include that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is, as @Martin Gal mentioned in the comments already, to use `dplyr::across`:

```
master_clean <- master_clean %>%
  mutate(nbNA_pt1 = rowSums(is.na(across(c(Q1:Q12)))),
         nbNA_pt2 = rowSums(is.na(across(c(Q13:Q20)))),
         nbNA_pt3 = rowSums(is.na(across(c(Q21:Q90))))
  )
```

The other option is to use `rowwise` and then you can replace `rowSums` with `sum` and use `c_across` instead of `across`. This approach is less performant and more usful in cases where we don't have vectorised functions that work on rows such as `rowSums`.

```
master_clean <- master_clean %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(nbNA_pt1 = sum(is.na(c_across(c(Q1:Q12)))),
         nbNA_pt2 = sum(is.na(c_across(c(Q13:Q20)))),
         nbNA_pt3 = sum(is.na(c_across(c(Q21:Q90))))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason why you can't use the variable name with mutate? Just so I can understand the logic!

Comment: @DavidPotrel: I'm not sure what you mean. We can use variable names inside `mutate` like in `nbNA_pt1 = nbNA_pt2` where we assign the right hand side value to the left hand side variable name. However, in your case you want to select several columns and this is not possible in `mutate` if "only" doing `Q1:Q12`.  To do this we need `across`, `c_across` or `select(., Q1:Q12)`.

Comment: [Here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) in the first paragraph is a good explanation of the two different types of {dplyr} verbs: `mutate` is a `<data-masking>` verb that lets you use data variables as if they were variables in the environment, whereas `select` uses `<tidy-select>` which lets you easily choose variables based on their position, name, or type.